# MySQL - Criar campo para inserir mais de um valor vindo de outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql, relacionamento

Seguinte, pode parecer uma dúvida básica mas preciso saber, vou direto ao ponto:

Tenho um cadastro de Jogadores e um cadastro de jogos(tabelas), referenciadas normalmente. Preciso saber como faço para que um jogador possa selecionar mais de um jogo de sua preferência, isto é , no campo 'jogo' da tabela 'jogadores' inserir mais de um valor, no caso quantos o 'jogador' decidir. Gostaria de uma ajuda sobre como fazer isso no banco de dados e se possível um ponto de partida pra fazer isso no php também. UTILIZO MYSQL + PHP no desenvolvimento. Obrigado

Comment: Isto parece-me uma relação muitos para muitos, então basta criar uma terceira tabela que faz esta ligação. Já estudou banco de dados relacional?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que você descreveu isso se torna uma relação de N para N, pois um jogador pode preferir de mais um jogo assim como um jogo pode ser preferido por mais de um jogador, nesse caso você deve cria um outra tabela com o id do jogador e id do jogo.[image: MER]

Comment: Eu concordo com essa resposta, mas em caso nao possa ou queira uma alternativa veja https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-values

Answer (score 0):

Você pode salvar os ID's dos jogos separados por "," Segue um exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE jogadores(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(50),
    jogo VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE jogos(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    descricao VARCHAR(255)
);


INSERT INTO jogos(descricao)VALUES('Jogo 1'),('Jogo 2'),('Jogo3'),('Jogo 4'),('Jogo 5');
INSERT INTO jogadores(nome, jogo)values('Jogador Teste', '1,3,5');
```

E quando for fazer usar o `JOIN` usar a função nativa do `MySQL` `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM jogadores j
INNER JOIN jogos jo
ON FIND_IN_SET(jo.id,j.jogo);
```

Nesse caso o resultado será:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]